# is there any need to use django forms while using reactjs in the frontend?

Tags: django, reactjs

I am  working with Django rest framework  and I  wonder if I can use reactjs as frontend framework, do I need to use Django forms in the backend (for validation purpose) ?

Answer (score 2):

> If you use React.js for front-end, You should be make Backend API with
>   validation for handle requests like POST Requests for handle forms and
>   GET Requests ...

Also you can handle form validation in React.js with some packages that depends on your project:

- [Formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik)
- [redux-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form)
- etc search in npmjs.com and github.com

Comment: so there is no need to use django forms ?

Comment: No need. In React you just need API for handle POST /GET requests. Backend like django, php or ... doesn't matter. You have to make  API.

Comment: Another great React form library: https://react-hook-form.com/